# How do I read integers line by line from stdin until an empty line is found then store these integers into an array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, user-input, stdin

I am trying to read ints from stdin line by line and store this into an array. I will know that I am done reading input when I get an empty line. However, when I run this code I don't seem to be exiting the loop because the program just hangs. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 int *nums;

 const int datacount = 10000;
  nums = malloc(sizeof(int) * datacount); 
  if (!nums) { 
    perror("Error allocating memory");
    abort();
  }

  memset(nums, 0, sizeof(int)*datacount);

  int cnt = 0;
  char line[64];


 while ((fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) && (line[0] !='\n') )    {

      if (sscanf(line, "%d", &nums[cnt]))
      {
         cnt++;
         fflush(stdout);
      } 

    }
```

Program will hang on sample input:

```
1
6
5
4
2
3
8
7
\n
```

Comment: Please add sample input and a few lines to make this a [mcve].

Comment: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html You are using fgets first, good, but in that article you will find some useful information of what can go wrong with any `scan` call.

Comment: @Yunnosch the OP has not used `scanf` in the first place.

Comment: @babon True, but in the second place. As I said, the article is not only about not using scanf.

Comment: Some remarks without analyzing it all: 1.) make it a [mcve] by adding sample input and a whole compilable source 2.) dynamic allocation of a fixed amount works, but seems unnecessary. 3.) This will fail with a line containing non-numeric characters, the `sscanf()` would then return `EOF`: Make it `if (sscanf(...) > 0)`. @Yunnosch, at a first glance, the error using `sscanf()` here seems minor, so thanks for linking my doc, but I don't think it applies here.

Comment: I tried it with `gcc` in Red Hat. Worked (as in didn't hang) for me.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: `\n` : Did you press only Enter-Key ?

Comment: Hmm okay I will try to compile it the way you are doing and separate this code into a file to make sure this is why it's hanging. I will also verify with gdb. Thanks.@KlasLindbäck

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce this, it works correctly with the given input, no matter whether I use literal `\n` or an actual newline. See my earlier comment for a potential bug in the code, but the actual problem must be something not included in the question.

Comment: Add `else printf("%d\n", line[0]);` after `if (sscanf(line, "%d", &nums[cnt]))
      {...
      }`.  does it report 13?